# Optimizing portable 128-bit integer shifts on a 32-bit architecture

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, integer, unsigned-integer

In my spare time I've been working on a utility library that among other things, supports signed/unsigned 128-bit integers. This library uses cpu-dispatching to utilize simd instructions in some cases, but requires a portable fallback so it will run everywhere else. Most recently I implemented the portable fallback for 128-bit shifting. It works correctly and runs reasonably fast, but it's not as fast as I'd like it to be, especially on 32-bit architectures.

Here's a stripped version with all relevant types and functionality(64-bit version included for completeness):

```
typedef uint32_t UInt32;
typedef int32_t Int32;
typedef uint64_t UInt64;
typedef int64_t Int64;

// Returns 0xFFFFFFFF if value != 0, otherwise returns 0.
UInt32 AllOrNothingMask32(Int32 value)
{
    return UInt32(-Int32(value != 0));
}

struct alignas(16) UInt128
{     
    // Ensure the layout matches the architecture.
    // LE = little endian
    // BE = big endian
#if CPU_TYPE == CPU_LE32
    UInt32 mLow;
    UInt32 mLowMid;
    UInt32 mHighMid;
    UInt32 mHigh;
#elif CPU_TYPE == CPU_BE32
    UInt32 mHigh;
    UInt32 mHighMid;
    UInt32 mLowMid;
    UInt32 mLow;
#elif CPU_TYPE == CPU_LE64
    UInt64 mLow;
    UInt64 mHigh;
#elif CPU_TYPE == CPU_BE64
    UInt64 mHigh;
    UInt64 mLow;
#endif

    UInt128() = default;

    UInt128& operator=(const UInt128& other) = default;

    inline
    UInt128(UInt32 high, UInt32 highMid, UInt32 lowMid, UInt32 low) :
#if CPU_SIZE == CPU_32BIT
        mLow(low),
        mLowMid(lowMid),
        mHighMid(highMid),
        mHigh(high) { }
#elif CPU_SIZE == CPU_64BIT
        mLow((UInt64(lowMid) << 32) | low),
        mHigh((UInt64(high) << 32) | highMid) { }
#endif

    inline
    UInt128(UInt64 high, UInt64 low) :
#if CPU_SIZE == CPU_32BIT
        mLow(UInt32(low)),
        mLowMid(UInt32(low >> 32)),
        mHighMid(UInt32(high)),
        mHigh(UInt32(high >> 32)) { }
#elif CPU_SIZE == CPU_64BIT
        mLow(low),
        mHigh(high) { }
#endif

    inline
    bool UInt128::operator==(const UInt128& other) const noexcept
    {
#if CPU_TYPE == CPU_32BIT
        return mLow == other.mLow &&
               mLowMid == other.mLowMid &&
               mHighMid == other.mHighMid &&
               mHigh == other.mHigh;
#elif CPU_TYPE == CPU_64BIT
        return mLow == other.mLow &&
               mHigh == other.mHigh;
#endif
    }

    inline
    UInt128& UInt128::operator<<=(Int32 shift) noexcept
    {
        // Shift is modulo 128, effectively clamping it between 0-127.
        shift &= 0x7F;
#if CPU_SIZE == CPU_32BIT
        auto low = mLow;
        auto lowMid = mLowMid;
        auto highMid = mHighMid;
        auto high = mHigh;

        if (shift == 0) {
            return *this;
        } else if (shift < 32) {
            auto rshift = 32 - shift;
            mLow = (low << shift);
            mLowMid = (lowMid << shift) | (low >> rshift);
            mHighMid = (highMid << shift) | (lowMid >> rshift);
            mHigh = (high << shift) | (highMid >> rshift);
        } else if (shift < 64) {
            auto lshift = (shift - 32);
            auto rshift = (32 - lshift) & 0x1F;
            auto rshiftMask = AllOrNothingMask32(rshift);
            mLow = 0;
            mLowMid = (low << lshift);
            mHighMid = (lowMid << lshift) | ((low >> rshift) & rshiftMask);
            mHigh = (highMid << lshift) | ((lowMid >> rshift) & rshiftMask);
        } else if (shift < 96) {
            auto lshift = (shift - 64);
            auto rshift = (64 - lshift) & 0x1F;
            auto rshiftMask = AllOrNothingMask32(rshift);
            mLow = 0;
            mLowMid = 0;
            mHighMid = (low << lshift);
            mHigh = (lowMid << lshift) | ((low >> rshift) & rshiftMask);
        } else {
            mLow = 0;
            mLowMid = 0;
            mHighMid = 0;
            mHigh = (low << (shift - 96));
        }
#elif CPU_SIZE == CPU_64BIT
        auto low = mLow,
             high = mHigh;

        if (shift == 0) {
            return *this;
        } else if (shift < 64) {
            mLow = (low << shift);
            mHigh = (high << shift) | (low >> (64 - shift));
        } else {
            mLow = 0;
            mHigh = (low << (shift - 64));
        }
#endif
        return *this;
    }

    inline
    UInt128& UInt128::operator>>=(Int32 shift) noexcept
    {
        // Shift is modulo 128, effectively clamping it between 0-127.
        shift &= 0x7F;
#if CPU_SIZE == CPU_32BIT
        auto low = mLow,
             lowMid = mLowMid,
             highMid = mHighMid,
             high = mHigh;

        if (shift == 0) {
            return *this;
        } else if (shift < 32) {
            auto rshift = 32 - shift;
            mLow = (low >> shift) | (lowMid << rshift);
            mLowMid = (lowMid >> shift) | (highMid << rshift);
            mHighMid = (highMid >> shift) | (high << rshift);
            mHigh = (high >> shift);
        } else if (shift < 64) {
            auto rshift = (shift - 32);
            auto lshift = (32 - rshift) & 0x1F;
            auto lshiftMask = AllOrNothingMask32(lshift);
            mLow = (lowMid >> rshift) | ((highMid << lshift) & lshiftMask);
            mLowMid = (highMid >> rshift) | ((high << lshift) & lshiftMask);
            mHighMid = (high >> rshift);
            mHigh = 0;
        } else if (shift < 96) {
            auto rshift = (shift - 64);
            auto lshift = (64 - rshift) & 0x1F;
            auto lshiftMask = AllOrNothingMask32(lshift);
            mLow = (highMid >> rshift) | ((high << lshift) & lshiftMask);
            mLowMid = (high >> rshift);
            mHighMid = 0;
            mHigh = 0;
        } else {
            mLow = (high >> (shift - 96));
            mLowMid = 0;
            mHighMid = 0;
            mHigh = 0;
        }
#elif CPU_SIZE == CPU_64BIT
        auto low = mLow,
             high = mHigh;

        if (shift == 0) {
            return *this;
        } else if (shift < 64) {
            mLow = (low >> shift) | (high << (64 - shift));
            mHigh = (high >> shift);
        } else {
            mLow = (high >> (shift - 64));
            mHigh = 0;
        }
#endif
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The relevant 32-bit assembly output is rather long, so unless requested I'm omitting it.

The main bottleneck is obviously branching when the shift argument isn't known at compile time. What can be done to eliminate branching, or for that matter what portable trickery can be utilized to speed this up?

**Update 1**

Added the copy assignment operator that was missing in the above example.
For those interested, here are the unit tests. I'm using Catch for it's simplicity.

```
// Left shift lookup table, from 0-127.
const UInt128 gLeftShiftLut128[] = {
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9988, 0x7766554433221100),
    UInt128(0xFFDDBB9977553310, 0xEECCAA8866442200),
    UInt128(0xFFBB7732EEAA6621, 0xDD995510CC884400),
    UInt128(0xFF76EE65DD54CC43, 0xBB32AA2199108800),
    UInt128(0xFEEDDCCBBAA99887, 0x7665544332211000),
    UInt128(0xFDDBB9977553310E, 0xECCAA88664422000),
    UInt128(0xFBB7732EEAA6621D, 0xD995510CC8844000),
    UInt128(0xF76EE65DD54CC43B, 0xB32AA21991088000),
    UInt128(0xEEDDCCBBAA998877, 0x6655443322110000),
    UInt128(0xDDBB9977553310EE, 0xCCAA886644220000),
    UInt128(0xBB7732EEAA6621DD, 0x995510CC88440000),
    UInt128(0x76EE65DD54CC43BB, 0x32AA219910880000),
    UInt128(0xEDDCCBBAA9988776, 0x6554433221100000),
    UInt128(0xDBB9977553310EEC, 0xCAA8866442200000),
    UInt128(0xB7732EEAA6621DD9, 0x95510CC884400000),
    UInt128(0x6EE65DD54CC43BB3, 0x2AA2199108800000),
    UInt128(0xDDCCBBAA99887766, 0x5544332211000000),
    UInt128(0xBB9977553310EECC, 0xAA88664422000000),
    UInt128(0x7732EEAA6621DD99, 0x5510CC8844000000),
    UInt128(0xEE65DD54CC43BB32, 0xAA21991088000000),
    UInt128(0xDCCBBAA998877665, 0x5443322110000000),
    UInt128(0xB9977553310EECCA, 0xA886644220000000),
    UInt128(0x732EEAA6621DD995, 0x510CC88440000000),
    UInt128(0xE65DD54CC43BB32A, 0xA219910880000000),
    UInt128(0xCCBBAA9988776655, 0x4433221100000000),
    UInt128(0x9977553310EECCAA, 0x8866442200000000),
    UInt128(0x32EEAA6621DD9955, 0x10CC884400000000),
    UInt128(0x65DD54CC43BB32AA, 0x2199108800000000),
    UInt128(0xCBBAA99887766554, 0x4332211000000000),
    UInt128(0x977553310EECCAA8, 0x8664422000000000),
    UInt128(0x2EEAA6621DD99551, 0xCC8844000000000),
    UInt128(0x5DD54CC43BB32AA2, 0x1991088000000000),
    UInt128(0xBBAA998877665544, 0x3322110000000000),
    UInt128(0x77553310EECCAA88, 0x6644220000000000),
    UInt128(0xEEAA6621DD995510, 0xCC88440000000000),
    UInt128(0xDD54CC43BB32AA21, 0x9910880000000000),
    UInt128(0xBAA9988776655443, 0x3221100000000000),
    UInt128(0x7553310EECCAA886, 0x6442200000000000),
    UInt128(0xEAA6621DD995510C, 0xC884400000000000),
    UInt128(0xD54CC43BB32AA219, 0x9108800000000000),
    UInt128(0xAA99887766554433, 0x2211000000000000),
    UInt128(0x553310EECCAA8866, 0x4422000000000000),
    UInt128(0xAA6621DD995510CC, 0x8844000000000000),
    UInt128(0x54CC43BB32AA2199, 0x1088000000000000),
    UInt128(0xA998877665544332, 0x2110000000000000),
    UInt128(0x53310EECCAA88664, 0x4220000000000000),
    UInt128(0xA6621DD995510CC8, 0x8440000000000000),
    UInt128(0x4CC43BB32AA21991, 0x880000000000000),
    UInt128(0x9988776655443322, 0x1100000000000000),
    UInt128(0x3310EECCAA886644, 0x2200000000000000),
    UInt128(0x6621DD995510CC88, 0x4400000000000000),
    UInt128(0xCC43BB32AA219910, 0x8800000000000000),
    UInt128(0x9887766554433221, 0x1000000000000000),
    UInt128(0x310EECCAA8866442, 0x2000000000000000),
    UInt128(0x621DD995510CC884, 0x4000000000000000),
    UInt128(0xC43BB32AA2199108, 0x8000000000000000),
    UInt128(0x8877665544332211, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x10EECCAA88664422, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x21DD995510CC8844, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x43BB32AA21991088, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x8776655443322110, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xEECCAA886644220 , 0x0),
    UInt128(0x1DD995510CC88440, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x3BB32AA219910880, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x7766554433221100, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xEECCAA8866442200, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xDD995510CC884400, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xBB32AA2199108800, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x7665544332211000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xECCAA88664422000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xD995510CC8844000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xB32AA21991088000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x6655443322110000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xCCAA886644220000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x995510CC88440000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x32AA219910880000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x6554433221100000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xCAA8866442200000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x95510CC884400000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x2AA2199108800000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x5544332211000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xAA88664422000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x5510CC8844000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xAA21991088000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x5443322110000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xA886644220000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x510CC88440000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xA219910880000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x4433221100000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x8866442200000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x10CC884400000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x2199108800000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x4332211000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x8664422000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xCC8844000000000 , 0x0),
    UInt128(0x1991088000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x3322110000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x6644220000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xCC88440000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x9910880000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x3221100000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x6442200000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0xC884400000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x9108800000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x2211000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x4422000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x8844000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x1088000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x2110000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x4220000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x8440000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x880000000000000 , 0x0),
    UInt128(0x1100000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x2200000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x4400000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x8800000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x1000000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x2000000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x4000000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x8000000000000000, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x0)
};
// Right shift lookup table, from 0-127.
const UInt128 gRightShiftLut128[] = {
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9988, 0x7766554433221100),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65DD54CC4, 0x3BB32AA219910880),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732EEAA662, 0x1DD995510CC88440),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB997755331, 0xEECCAA886644220),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA998, 0x8776655443322110),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65DD54CC, 0x43BB32AA21991088),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732EEAA66, 0x21DD995510CC8844),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB99775533, 0x10EECCAA88664422),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA99, 0x8877665544332211),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65DD54C, 0xC43BB32AA2199108),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732EEAA6, 0x621DD995510CC884),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB9977553, 0x310EECCAA8866442),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9, 0x9887766554433221),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65DD54, 0xCC43BB32AA219910),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732EEAA, 0x6621DD995510CC88),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB997755, 0x3310EECCAA886644),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA, 0x9988776655443322),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65DD5, 0x4CC43BB32AA21991),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732EEA, 0xA6621DD995510CC8),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB99775, 0x53310EECCAA88664),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBA, 0xA998877665544332),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65DD, 0x54CC43BB32AA2199),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732EE, 0xAA6621DD995510CC),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB9977, 0x553310EECCAA8866),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBB, 0xAA99887766554433),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65D, 0xD54CC43BB32AA219),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732E, 0xEAA6621DD995510C),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB997, 0x7553310EECCAA886),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCB, 0xBAA9988776655443),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE65, 0xDD54CC43BB32AA21),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7732, 0xEEAA6621DD995510),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB99, 0x77553310EECCAA88),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDCC, 0xBBAA998877665544),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE6, 0x5DD54CC43BB32AA2),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB773, 0x2EEAA6621DD99551),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB9, 0x977553310EECCAA8),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDDC, 0xCBBAA99887766554),
    UInt128(0x7FF76EE, 0x65DD54CC43BB32AA),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB77, 0x32EEAA6621DD9955),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDBB, 0x9977553310EECCAA),
    UInt128(0xFFEEDD, 0xCCBBAA9988776655),
    UInt128(0x7FF76E, 0xE65DD54CC43BB32A),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB7, 0x732EEAA6621DD995),
    UInt128(0x1FFDDB, 0xB9977553310EECCA),
    UInt128(0xFFEED, 0xDCCBBAA998877665),
    UInt128(0x7FF76, 0xEE65DD54CC43BB32),
    UInt128(0x3FFBB, 0x7732EEAA6621DD99),
    UInt128(0x1FFDD, 0xBB9977553310EECC),
    UInt128(0xFFEE, 0xDDCCBBAA99887766),
    UInt128(0x7FF7, 0x6EE65DD54CC43BB3),
    UInt128(0x3FFB, 0xB7732EEAA6621DD9),
    UInt128(0x1FFD, 0xDBB9977553310EEC),
    UInt128(0xFFE, 0xEDDCCBBAA9988776),
    UInt128(0x7FF, 0x76EE65DD54CC43BB),
    UInt128(0x3FF, 0xBB7732EEAA6621DD),
    UInt128(0x1FF, 0xDDBB9977553310EE),
    UInt128(0xFF, 0xEEDDCCBBAA998877),
    UInt128(0x7F, 0xF76EE65DD54CC43B),
    UInt128(0x3F, 0xFBB7732EEAA6621D),
    UInt128(0x1F, 0xFDDBB9977553310E),
    UInt128(0xF, 0xFEEDDCCBBAA99887),
    UInt128(0x7, 0xFF76EE65DD54CC43),
    UInt128(0x3, 0xFFBB7732EEAA6621),
    UInt128(0x1, 0xFFDDBB9977553310),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9988),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65DD54CC4),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732EEAA662),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB997755331),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCBBAA998),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65DD54CC),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732EEAA66),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB99775533),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCBBAA99),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65DD54C),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732EEAA6),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB9977553),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65DD54),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732EEAA),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB997755),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCBBAA),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65DD5),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732EEA),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB99775),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCBBA),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65DD),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732EE),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB9977),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCBB),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65D),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732E),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB997),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCCB),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE65),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7732),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB99),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDCC),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE6),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB773),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB9),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDDC),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76EE),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB77),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDBB),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEEDD),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76E),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB7),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDDB),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEED),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF76),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFBB),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFDD),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFEE),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF7),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FFB),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FFD),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFFE),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7FF),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3FF),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1FF),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xFF),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7F),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3F),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1F),
    UInt128(0x0, 0xF),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x7),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x3),
    UInt128(0x0, 0x1)
};

TEST_CASE("UInt128 left shift produces correct results.") {
    auto base = UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9988, 0x7766554433221100);

    for (auto i = 1; i <= 127; i++) {
        auto sample = base;
        sample <<= i;

        INFO("i = " << i);
        REQUIRE(sample == gLeftShiftLut128[i]);
    }
}

TEST_CASE("UInt128 right shift produces correct results.") {
    auto base = UInt128(0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9988, 0x7766554433221100);

    for (auto i = 0; i <= 127; i++) {
        auto sample = base;
        sample >>= i;

        INFO("i = " << i);
        REQUIRE(sample == gRightShiftLut128[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, not really an optimization, but you might try to simplify the code by implementing shifting as "rotate words by `shift // 32` places (if quotient non-zero), then use either the shift == 0 or shift < 32 code path to rotate at the bit level". Or even go down to the byte level, so one in eight shifts is just byteswapping, with no bit shifting at all. You can use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to do the word or byte swapping for you, which both simplifies your code further, and (ideally) means you're getting optimal rotation code.

Comment: Keep in mind, simplifying the code here will, if nothing else, help with code cache on the CPU. Inlining this much code over and over is going to hurt on binary size too. So you might get wins simply out of less complex/repetitive code by simplifying.

Comment: I had considered simplification but nothing came to mind that handles all of the scenarios portably. I have an asm routine that works and some experimental intrinsic variants, but obviously those aren't portable.

Comment: on 64-bit targets and GCC/Clang you can simply use [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html). That's the best way, no need to mess with the narrow integers yourself

Answer (score 1):

I haven't benchmarked it, but something like this is branchless:

```
inline
UInt128& UInt128::operator<<=(Int32 shift) noexcept
{
    auto lshift = shift & 31;
    auto rshift = 31 - lshift;
    UInt32 parts[8] = {
#if CPU_TYPE == CPU_LE32
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        mLow << lshift,
        mLowMid << lshift | mLow >> 1 >> rshift,
        mHighMid << lshift | mLowMid >> 1 >> rshift,
        mHigh << lshift | mHighMid >> 1 >> rshift
#elif CPU_TYPE == CPU_BE32
        mHigh << lshift | mHighMid >> 1 >> rshift,
        mHighMid << lshift | mLowMid >> 1 >> rshift,
        mLowMid << lshift | mLow >> 1 >> rshift,
        mLow << lshift,
        0, 0, 0, 0
#endif
    };
    memcpy(this, &parts[
#if CPU_TYPE == CPU_LE32
        4 -
#endif
        (shift >> 5 & 3)], 16);
    return *this;
}

inline
UInt128& UInt128::operator>>=(Int32 shift) noexcept
{
    auto rshift = shift & 31;
    auto lshift = 31 - rshift;
    UInt32 parts[8] = {
#if CPU_TYPE == CPU_LE32
    mLow >> rshift | mMidLow << lshift << 1,
    mMidLow >> rshift | mMidHigh << lshift << 1,
    mMidHigh >> rshift | mHigh << lshift << 1,
    mHigh >> rshift,
    0, 0, 0, 0
#elif CPU_TYPE == CPU_BE32
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    mHigh >> rshift,
    mMidHigh >> rshift | mHigh << lshift << 1,
    mMidLow >> rshift | mMidHigh << lshift << 1,
    mLow >> rshift | mMidLow << lshift << 1
#endif
    };
    memcpy(this, &parts[
#if CPU_TYPE == CPU_BE32
        4 -
#endif
        (shift >> 5 & 3)], 16);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Fails on my unit tests, but I can definitely see this working with some tweaking. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @KobyDuck Oops, it's probably failing because `>> rshift` restricted to [0..7] only works if you pick off the high byte first. Well, you can tell how much I tested this :) There's not really a good reason to limit the shifting to within a byte, not sure why I decided to write it that way.

Comment: Updated it to use your most recent changes, modifying rshift's value to ((32 - lshift) & 31) so it doesn't trigger undefined behavior when right shifting by 32. Still fails, but you've got me on the right track. I'll post my unit testing code shortly.

Comment: @KobyDuck Oh drat, I do actually depend on `>> 32 == 0` in the revised code. Hmm, that's fixable by splitting the shift up to `>> 1 >> (31 - lshift)`. But I'll wait for your test cases to confirm, since mental arithmetic doesn't seem to be working for me too well :) That was actually not broken when I was shifting by smaller amounts...

Comment: @KobyDuck It is maybe working now. If you do go this route, I think `struct UInt128 { UInt32 mData[4]; } memcpy(&mData)` is better than `memcpy(this)`, but that shouldn't make any practical difference.

Comment: I've been testing your latest version with some changes. Your version verbatim fails, but I have faith. The bits are falling into place haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138385/discussion-between-ephemient-and-koby-duck).

Answer (score 1):

I would think a `UInt128` would be better implemented using an array, where the endianness is not an issue, e.g.,

`alignas (16) uint32_t data[4];` or: `alignas (16) uint64_t data[2];`

Note that alignment will not be guaranteed for objects created on the heap; though some ABIs do have 16 byte minimum alignment. You can check with `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. If not, you will need to replace the global operator new and delete functions for SIMD (e.g., SSE).

For `uint32_t` implementation, you split the shift into 'word' and 'bit' shifts - also, it doesn't make sense to have a *signed* Int32 as a shift count...

```
inline UInt128 &
UInt128::operator <<= (uint32_t shift) noexcept
{
    shift &= 0x7f;
    auto shw = shift / (32); // or (shift >> 5)
    auto shl = shift % (32); // or (shift & 1f)

    // branch-free shift masking:

    uint32_t shm = shl - 1;
    uint32_t shr = (- shl) & (32 - 1);
    shm = (shm >> (32 - 1)) - 1; // 0xffffffff or 0x0

    switch (shw)
    {
    case (3) :
        data[3] = (data[0] << shl);
        data[2] = 0, data[1] = 0, data[0] = 0;
        break;

    case (2) :
        data[3] = (data[1] << shl) | ((data[0] >> shr) & shm);
        data[2] = (data[0] << shl);
        data[1] = 0, data[0] = 0;
        break;

    case (1) :
        data[3] = (data[2] << shl) | ((data[1] >> shr) & shm);
        data[2] = (data[1] << shl) | ((data[0] >> shr) & shm);
        data[1] = (data[0] << shl);
        data[0] = 0;
        break;

    case (0) : // default:
        data[3] = (data[3] << shl) | ((data[2] >> shr) & shm);
        data[2] = (data[2] << shl) | ((data[1] >> shr) & shm);
        data[1] = (data[1] << shl) | ((data[0] >> shr) & shm);
        data[0] = (data[0] << shl);
        // break;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have the data indices correct here. If `shift` is a compile time constant, the compiler should be able to optimize this code pretty aggressively.

I'll leave *right* shift to you, except you will have to update `data` from low to high words, so as to not overwrite the words before they are read. Otherwise, it should mostly be a simple exercise in swapping the roles of `shl` and `shr`. A `uint64_t` data version should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: The endian dependency is only for the parts(low, high, etc) so that other methods can refer to the parts they need without requiring additional ifdef soup. i.e. cast operators, (and/or/xor) bitwise ops with a smaller type argument, etc. Also, I'm optimizing for the case where shift isn't known at compile time. When it is known, the optimizer usually eliminates branches.

Comment: The type uses alignas(16), apparently I stripped that out by mistake. The use of a signed argument is simply a convention; masking sanitizes the value.

Comment: @KobyDuck - compilers are pretty good at optimizing case statements like these into jump tables, which is perhaps why `default:` might be a better hint than `case 0:` as a label. It would also seem trivial to replace `data[i]` with the corresponding `mHigh/Low` variables.